# Insert with multiple select statement if not exist

Tags: mysql

I'd tried insert with multiple statement with the code below

```
insert into peoplePos
select a.name,b.option
FROM (SELECT name from people t1) a
JOIN (SELECT option FROM optionTable WHERE name = 'Position') b
where not exists (select * from peoplePos t2 where t2.name = t1.name);
```

However i got this error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.name' in 'where clause'

It seems in the where clause, `t1` cant access the people `t1` declared earlier

I'd tried using `a.t1.name` and `people.name`, both doesn't work

Is there away to access it? Thanks

Comment: quoting mysql documentation **Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause**

Comment: But "a" is a sub query alias.
It seems to be working for him now.

Comment: yes, using where `t2.name = a.name` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think you'd want some conditions on your join, but for what you ask, t1 does not exist.  You have aliased it as a so use a.

```
    insert into peoplePos
    select a.name,b.option
    FROM (SELECT name from people t1) a
    JOIN (SELECT option FROM optionTable WHERE name = 'Position') b ON "SOME CONDITION OR OTHER"
    where not exists (select * from peoplePos t2 where t2.name = a.name);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, issue solved. Thanks for pointing out of the join too, but i didn't intent to put any condition i use `join` because i cant do `insert into peoplePos, select name from people, select option from optionTable`